# Script Alert Error: Object expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been working for a few days on a SUP project that needs some customization and I get the error `Script Alert Error: Object expected`

The code I've introduced is:

```
 $('#bottomOfStart_ScreenForm').before('<div style="display:none">');
   $('#bottomOfStart_ScreenForm').before('<label style="display:none" for="Descarca_PK">Descarca</label>');
   $('#bottomOfStart_ScreenForm').before('<input style="display:none" class="rightcheckbox" type="checkbox" name="Descarca_PK" id="Descarca_PK" sup_html_type="checkbox" sup_default_value="true" checked="yes" disabled="disabled"></input>');
   $('#bottomOfStart_ScreenForm').before('</div>');
```

(Here is a link with the code, it seems it gets interpreted :P http://img22.imageshack.us/img22/927/axq6.jpg )

I even tried with something like

```
var bottomOfFormElem = document.getElementById("bottomOfStart_ScreenForm");
bottomOfFormElem.innerHTML = "<p>&nbsp;</p>";
```

I receive this error only on a Windows CE 6.1 Intermec CK3 device, but on any other device I've used (Android only) it works just fine.

Do you have any suggestion to what can I do?

Comment: jquery is probably not supported on such an old device...

Comment: Is there another solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is some problem with jquery. Is your browser older than ie9? Can look for the line number where the problem is being reported and reply back with the same?

Comment: Yes it is older. SUP doesn't call a browser window. It's in a container downloaded from SAP.